# Set Margins programmatically for Navigationview support design library

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I have implemented **Navigation Drawer** using **NavigationView** from design support library. I want to change the **margins of nav drawer** depending on the **nav menu** item selected. Basically I want that **NavDrawer** should always be **below the toolbar** and tabs, if present. 
I tried below code to set the **top margin** but it doesn't work. No APP crash **but drawer doesn't open** when I click **hamburger icon**. Pls help SO community.

```
DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams)mNavigationView.getLayoutParams();    
params.setMargins(0,72,0,0);           
mNavigationView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: where do you open nav view?could you show more code?

Comment: @Nazila never mind.. I have moved on from Android to Xamarin. :)